# How to call function at the very end of the submit event, after all callbacks are finished?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, submit

Can somebody tell me please, how can I call the function after all submit event callbacks are done? I have something like this, but I need to have it at the very end of the submit callbacks.

```
$('#form').on('submit', function () {
    tour.next();
});
```

The problem with this is, there are other callbacks which trigger after this one. So again, how can I add a handler at the very end of the submit call stack?

Comment: Event callbacks are 
`$('.xxx').on('click', function () {
    alert('callback one');
});
$('.xxx').on('click', function () {
    alert('callback two');
});` As you can see there are tho callbacks.

Comment: Don't post code essential to your question in comments (it's unreadable), edit it into your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

If `tour.next();` and the other callbacks are synchronous, then just call `setTimeout` to run a function at the end:

```
setTimeout(somethingToRunAtEnd);
```

and it'll run after all the other handlers are finished.

If they're asynchronous, then make sure they return Promises and then `Promise.all` over each of them:

```
let promises;
$('.xxx').on('click', function() {
  promises = [alert('callback one')];
});
$('.xxx').on('click', function() {
  promises.push(alert('callback two'));
  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    console.log('all asyncs finished');
  });
});
```

(pretty hacky, much better to simply assign a single handler rather than many)

Comment: Are you sure the setTimeout callback will be done before redirect? Isnt it in separate callstack? I mean submit event set timer and is done. but timer have its own stack havent it?

Comment: It looks redirect after submit triggers before setTimeout callback is done.

Comment: With something like that, there won't be any room for a `callback 3` after `submit` because the page will be replaced - the script will be terminated. No, it doesn't go onto a separate call stack - it'll be put at the end of the same (only) one.

Comment: And if I set timer without second time parameter it will be executed? Cause it seems its is not.

Comment: In a submit handler, you need to call `preventDefault` to keep the page from being replaced - but then, you can call whatever functions (synchronous or asynchronous) that you want, and they'll run.